# Iphone Web put and get

Tags: iphone, get, put

All,

I need to create an app for work that signs into our website using SSL and returns our member information.

I have figured out how to log in but am not sure how to find the id tags that I want to bring into my app and store to be show in a table view.

I know how to do these three things.

Put in username and password, 
authenticate against website, 
create session cookie.

Not sure how to do these things.

Get information about member, ie, how long a member , sustaining member, ect from the website knowing the tags for these fields on the site.
Store the data (core data?) or flat file. Shouldn't be that much information.
Format and present data in table view.

Lots of information here about getting files or whole websites but not so much about picking information off websites for concise viewing.

Thanks.

Comment: "picking information off websites"  - are you using an API that your company has or are you scraping content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your company's site is designed to provide this information through a web service, then it should be as simple as constructing your request URLs appropriately. If it has not been designed to interact with anything but humans, then you're probably going to have to do a great deal of work parsing HTML which no one can really help you with unless said site is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services should work fine with our website.

Comment: Then ask someone who knows how they work to explain how you can consume the data they publish.